# You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project in API javascript map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, google-api

You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project at [https://console.cloud.google.com/project/\_/billing/enable](https://console.cloud.google.com/project/%5C_/billing/enable) Learn more at https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started

I used API javascript map to fetch mas data but i found an error that "This page can't load Google Maps correctly"

Comment: Just enable billing in your project on Google cloud console.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.